# flutter web TypeError: dart.global.firebase.storage is not a function

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am building a web app in flutter trying to add photos to firebase storage.

I am having this error and most post say its solve by adding

[https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.4/firebase-database.js"](https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.4/firebase-database.js%22)

but I have it

What else could be causing the TypeError: dart.global.firebase.storage is not a function

```
<body>
<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.4/firebase-app.js"></script>

<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.4/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.4/firebase-firestore.js"></script>


<script>
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: "",
    measurementId: ""
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.analytics();
</script>
</script>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same issue and fixed it by adding the another script for firebase-storage

```
...
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.4/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.4/firebase-storage.js"></script>
...
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this in index.html, it will work (see that you insert it in the right place)

```
  

    ..................    
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
          firebase.analytics();
        </script>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
          <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
        </body>
        </html>
```